# Variable list of pairs as function argument

Tags: c++

Is there no means of passing a variable list of pairs to a (template) function ?

This does not compile :

```cpp
bool bNBR, bSWAP; int s, n;
foo({ s, bSWAP }, { n, bNBR }); // {...}, end: the bools indicate if ints != 0
```

The only way I could come up with was to `#define Mfoo(...) foo({__VA_ARGS__})` (foo taking a vector of pairs, for example).

Is the naked list of pairs not manageable ?

Comment: What is it about `pair`s that makes this question different than non-pair arguments?

Comment: If `foo`'s parameter is a `std::initializer_list<std::tuple<int, bool>>`, and there's an extra pair of braces slapped around the whole thing, then this should work... Otherwise you'll need to [edit] your question and add more detail.

Comment: `{ s, bSWAP }` does not have a type because there is literally an infinite number of types it could have.  Since it doesn't have a type, no type deduction can happen.

Comment: Declare your function with one parameter:  `std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>`.  The vector can contain zero or more parameters, *and* you can test the size of the container to see how many parameters have been passe.  Also, you can iterate through the vector processing the parameters.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik : the point is avoiding the added {}. That's what the macro in my question exactly does. Then, many types of arguments will work (vector of pairs, list of tuples (@Sam), .. the "infinite" possibilities Nathan is talking about). My question is specifically about the *naked* list of pairs.

Comment: The referred question in the duplicate warning does not answer mine.  Other than incidentally saying : no, not possible (which seems to be the correct answer, unfortunately). Robert's answer there is what I'm looking for (apparently), except it doesn't compile (unless you de-template the template for the compiler, as per the single comment he got).

Comment: In that case, that's not possible, C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: 'C++' does have `#define` that "can make it happen". `({ s, bSWAP }, { n, bNBR })` is cumbersome enough, `#define` it is. The strong type system is your friend.. most of the time.